# RobotFramework Output

Tags: python, robotframework

Im totally newb with Python and RobotFramework, but I have created few tests with Robot Framework (SSHLibrary), I have mini-PC with Linux Mint installed where I take SSH and check IP/Hostname/Hardware/Move simple file to it and give acces to it etc.

And now I'd like to get modified report.html from it.

I just need to list there which tests passed/failed (Maybe Set Test Message or any other test specified text there) and want to brand that with my own logo and it should be bit more stylized than that default reprot/log.html files.

So I need step by step where to start and maybe short example, I want to learn how to start and then expand it by my own.

PS. I have no idea how to run .py files after execution of tests so if someone could tell me that also :) Sorry for my noobines

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). 
Please check [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as [On Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no build in mechanism to modify report.html - you could write your own Listener plugin that would generate the output you like.

Comment: Do you have an example of how that works? I've tried to figure out that but still no results

Comment: https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/blob/master/doc/userguide/src/ExtendingRobotFramework/ListenerInterface.rst